# MONGO_URL is undefined eventhough .env is existing

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, mern

.env file contains

```
MONGO_URL = mongodb+srv://*****:******@cluster0.beu7d9.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority;
(username & password is hidden here)
```

I have installed "dotenv" file and in file index.js I have written the following code

```
require('dotenv').config()

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
```

When I try to run console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL) ,it shows "undefined". I tried a lot but it keeps on showing undefined. what should I need to change to work this

Comment: Are you starting your Node.js app from the directory that contains the `.env` file? `require('dotenv').config({ debug : true })` might provide a clue.

Comment: @robertklep its not working again

Comment: I'm just running and checking the cosole.log(process.env.MONGO_URL) from vs code run & debug option. Is there any other way to run and check the result'

Comment: If you're running from VS Code it's likely that it's not setting the correct working directory.

Comment: @robertklep then how to run it ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, `dotenv` will look for a file named `.env` *in the current working directory*.

If you start your code from another directory (which is typically the case if you run it from something like VS Code), the file won't be found.

You can tell `dotenv` to look for the file in a different directory, for instance in the directory where the file is from which you include it:

```
const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config({ path : path.resolve(__dirname, '.env') });
```